# Create jquery navigation

Tags: jquery

Ok, I have a file with bootstrap navigation, something like this:

```
        <ul class="nav nav-pills  ">
            <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Početna</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Programiranje <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/strana/programskijezici">Programski jezici</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/baze_cms">Baze podataka & CMS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
     E learning <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/php_tutorijali">PHP tutorijali</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/books">Knjige</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/comments">Pitanja & komentari</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

I am trying to add a class when it is clicked on some link:

```
<script>
$("li").on( "click", function() {
  console.log(33333);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that link refresh happens, the class isn't added, because the page is loaded once again.

Comment: You have a href tag so it will refresh for sure .What did you expect?

Comment: is there some way to add class after refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question , best way is :

Use selecting "Active" menu(apply class to div) in PHP.

Check your url in php. If you are using codeignitor, check if current controller , function is `xyz` , if yes then apply class "Active" to xyz menu.

Comment: thing is in codeIgniter i try to build one navigation view and different bodies, you gave me idea to set some variable give vote up to my question stack will block my acc tnx